# Received Serial string doesn't enter the if -statement in Visual studio C# while the string seems to contain the right value

Tags: c#, uart, serial-communication

I have a device which sends "go" through serial communication. I want my application to act on that command, however it seems to have some kind of a bug.

The following code doesn't enter the if-statement, however when I print dataIN1 in a textbox is does print "go" in the textbox.

```
dataIN1 = serialPort1.ReadExisting(); // Read incoming data from serial port 1

if (dataIN1 == "go") {        //if 'go' is send, check cBox and start program for programming
```

Weirdly the following change does work:

```
dataIN1 = serialPort1.ReadExisting(); // Read incoming data from serial port 1
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = dataIN1;});
string test2 = textBox1.Text;

if (test2 == "go") {        //if 'go' is send, check cBox and start program for programming
```

dataIN1 is a global string.

putting dataIN1 directly in test2 doesn't work as well.

I also tried:

```
   string test = dataIN1;

   string test2 = Test + dataIN1;
```

In case it sends g and o separately.

I don't want to use a textbox for it to work, does anyone has any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

[This code is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkjUT.png)

[this code is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns3K5.png)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you want Visual Studio - the application you use to edit your code - to react to serial inputs, unless you're writing a Visual Studio extension that allows you to remotely control it via serial (which would be a really weird thing to make).

Comment: You sure there isn't a NUL character at the end of the input string?

Comment: Inspect the actual value of that dataIN1 in the debugger - are you sure there are no hidden characters there (NULL, CR/LF etc)? - Compare the lengths of dataIN1 and test2

Comment: It might send a NUL character at the end of the string, I'm not sure, but changing to: if(dataIN1 == "go\0"){ doesnt work as well

Comment: If it's not immediately obvious visually when debugging, change your code to iterate the characters within the string and inspect each `Char`. Confim how many you actually see and their values. My own guess would be line ending characters.

Comment: I think it did send a NUL character. I changed the statementment to if(dataIN1.Contains("go")){   and this works! thanks guys.

Comment: I’m trying to figure out why you’re spitting text out to a text box vice using a debug breakpoint.